# How to obtain the location of a dategrid within a table layout

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, location

I have a Windows form and I am using table layout panels to keep the form looking nice.
I have a datagrid in the bottom right corner and I want to find the location of this datagrid relating to the top left of the Windows form.

The only location I can find is it's location I  relation to the table layout cell.

The ultimate plan is to move a combobox on top of a selected cell, I can find the select cell location but because  this is again relating to the table layout, the combo box is out of alignment.

---

I originally tried adding a new column with a combo box linked because I have been told converting a column to a combo box is impossible once the adaptor.Fill() has been run.
Code for adding combo boxes, this was causing the error were all row are marked as dirty and cause the update command to take a while to update.

```
    if (dataGridView1.Columns.Contains("myComboColumn"))
        dataGridView1.Columns.Remove("myComboColumn")
            ; 

    // gets column index number
    int i = dataGridView1.Columns["Has the machine been replaced?"].Index;

    // Hide original column
    dataGridView1.Columns["Has the machine been replaced?"].Visible = true;
    // combo box in datagrid attempt 2

    DataGridViewComboBoxColumn cmbCol = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();

    cmbCol.HeaderText = dataGridView1.Columns[i].HeaderText;

    cmbCol.Name = "myComboColumn";
    cmbCol.Items.Add("Yes");
    cmbCol.Items.Add("No");

    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(cmbCol);
    //   dataGridView1.Columns["myComboColumn" + i].DisplayIndex = 0;

    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        row.Cells["myComboColumn"].Value = row.Cells["Has the machine been replaced?"].Value;

    }
```

Comment: A DataGridView con contain DataGridViewComboBoxColumns so you dont have to do it the hard way

Comment: I am using ms access data source and the adaptor fill command to populate the grid. No option to add combo boxes this was

Comment: You have to swap out the default column because it cant tell which ones might be a CBO.  But once you do and set a DataSource, its all integrated.

Comment: I managed to do that but it created another problem.  Because I insert a new column, it marked every row state as dirty.  Meaning my update took a while.  I want to keep all row states as clean making any updates faster.  Guess it depends which problem is easier to solve

Comment: To what thing did you add the column?  Such a change to the DGV wont change the data

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47948159 shows some of my code.  I am not using the gui data source option in visual studio. I was told adding using code will not allow me to amend existing columns and instead I had to create another column with combo, hide the original column and do a link.  Do you have any links showing your suggestion